# Printschema() in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

```
Dataset<Tweet> ds = sc.read().json("/path").as(Encoders.bean(Tweet.class));



Tweet class :-
long id
string user;
string text;


ds.printSchema();
```

Output:-

```
root
  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
  |-- text: string (nullable = true)  
  |-- user: string (nullable = true)
```

json file has all arguments of string type

My question is am taking input and encoding it as `Tweet.class` .The datatype specified for id in the schema is Long but when schema is printed it is cast to `String`.

Does it give printscheme a/c to how it reads the file or according to encoding we do (here Tweet.class)?

Comment: I think the schema is determined from the file, so it finds a string. But "as" method converted it as a long. Do'nt worry, your result is a Dataset<Tweet> so your field id is mandatory a long.

Comment: No thats not true if am specifying in Tweet class id as long and i took it from json as string,further actions like ds.first() would go into error and would say no constructor found for actual parameters

Comment: Ah so the parsing doesn't work. So it's because the ID field is a string.

Comment: That what the question is how is that giving ID field as string when it is defined as long in tweet.class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i don't know the exact reason why your code is not working, but if you want to change the filed type you can write your customSchema.

```
val schema =  StructType(List
                        (
                          StructField("id", LongType, nullable = true),
                          StructField("text", StringType, nullable = true),
                          StructField("user", StringType, nullable = true)
                        )))
```

you can apply schema to your dataframe as follows:

```
Dataset<Tweet> ds = sc.read().schema(schema).json("/path")

ds.printSchema()
```

Comment: {"id":"572692378957430785,""user":"Srkian_nishu :)","text":"@always_nidhi @YouTube no i dnt understand bt i loved the music nd their dance awesome all the song of this mve is rocking"}

here id is a string,is this a reason?

Comment: because as soon as a manipulate data and remove quotes from id like
{"id":572692378957430785,"user":"Srkian_nishu :)","text":"@always_nidhi @YouTube no i dnt understand bt i loved the music nd their dance awesome all the song of this mve is rocking"}
Now it correctly gives me the answer id:long

Comment: that might be the reason, better to replace quotes in id and use.

Comment: I might do or I might prefer to type cast it but thats not the question
The question is when am specifying ENCODERS.bean(Tweet.class) still  it is giving me id:string